# Difference between Content Repository and RDBMS?

Tags: mysql, apache, web, rdbms, jackrabbit

Many websites use some content repository (like apache Jackrabbit) for storing the data. What is the main difference between a Content repository and an RDBMS and when to use what ?

Comment: May be useful: [JCR or RDBMS: why, when, how?](http://dev.day.com/content/ddc/blog/2009/01/jcrrdbmsreport/_jcr_content/images/jcrrdbmsreport/jcr_rdbms_report_chapuis.pdf).